# Decoding the "0501..." strings used by SigningType.MICHELINE

Tags: taquito, python

Is there a trick to decoding the "0501..." strings used by SigningType.MICHELINE. I am trying to unpack it from python using:

```
from pytezos.michelson.types import MichelsonType

ty = MichelsonType.match({'prim': 'string'})
ty.unpack(bytes.fromhex('0501...')).to_python_object()
```

I always get an error that it is the wrong number of bytes though, any thoughts? Do I just need to pass the original length and manually unpack?

```
pytezos.michelson.micheline.MichelsonRuntimeError: not enough bytes to parse array body, wanted 3291190
```

There is some inconsistency in the docs here: https://tezostaquito.io/docs/signing#generating-a-signature-with-beacon-sdk

The first padding example is different from the full signing code. I think maybe the full example has the wrong padding for the standards?

Comment: Could you provide the entire string you have problems with (or any random string, just for example), so we can check it?

Comment: Will do asap when I get it from the person that has the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the example in the docs was wrong and it is now corrected, that was the problem.

Correct example in signing docs:

[image]

https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/pull/2399/files